# How to add a Tab on magento backend config

Tags: xml, magento, backend

I've spent hours trying to add a new tab to the menu on the backend of Magento system configuration, followed multiple tutorials, but it still doesn't show up.
The code I've written:
app/code/local/packagename/helloWorld/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <helloconfig translate="label" module="helloworld">
        <label>Hello Config</label>
        <sort_order>99999</sort_order>
    </helloconfig>
</tabs> 
<sections>
    <helloworld_options translate="label" module="helloworld">
        <label>Hello World Config Options</label>
        <tab>helloconfig</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>  
        <groups>
            <messages translate="label">
                <label>Demo Of Config Fields</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                
            </messages>
        </groups>           
    </helloworld_options>
</sections> 
</config>
```

and 
app/code/local/packagename/helloWorld/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config>
<global>
<helpers>
    <helloworld>
        <class>packagename_Helloworld_Helper</class>
    </helloworld>
</helpers>  
</global>
</config>
```

and the obligatory Helper
app/code/local/packagename/helloWorld/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class packagename_Helloworld_Helper_Data 
extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
?>
```

The Cache is turned off.

So as far as I've understood it, this should add a new tab to the menu under System->Configuration on Magento backend. But it does not.
So maybe someone has an answer to this, it would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the module in config.xml file.

Like this

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <helloworld>
                <class>packagename_Helloworld_Helper</class>
            </helloworld>
        </helpers>  
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot this, but it won't help, nothing really changed

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to add a "category" which will automatically add your content to the menu, and then use the url rewrite option to direct where the menu item is calling and directed to.

For more info on the following please refer to : [http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index]